# Type error using react-cool-inview ('RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, viewport

I've installed `react-cool-inview` using `yarn add react-cool-inview`.

Then I imported it and used it on a component `(MyComponent.tsx)`:

```
import React from "react";
import useInView from "react-cool-inview";

const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  interface onEnterArgs {
    unobserve: () => void;
  }

  const { ref } = useInView({
    onEnter: ({ unobserve }: onEnterArgs) => {
      unobserve();
      console.log("Got it");
    },
  });

  return (
    <div ref={ref}> // lint error on this line
      Hi there
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

When running my TypeScript app, I get the following type build error:

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'.  TS2322
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useInView` is returning a ref for a general `HTMLElement`, but the `div` wants a ref that is specifically for a div aka `HTMLDivElement`.

Fortunately the `useInView` function accepts a generic variable that you can use to set the type of the element.

```
const { ref } = useInView<HTMLDivElement>({ ...
```

This will return the correct type of `ref` for a `div`.

Comment: Great, thank you! I tried looking at the demo for problems with my code but didn't spot this line https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-inview/blob/d4201eb4eac68ff8687524d92e3b4965c4674506/demo/Card/index.tsx#L10